# Gitlab - path to git command

Tags: gitlab, centos

I have took over sel-hosted gitlab from former co-worker. I have a qustion about git version/location which gitlab use because I wanted to do upgrade which require git 2.31.x and later. Server is CentOS 7.9. I have found several different versions in the system. How do I find which one is used by gitlab?

By "yum list installed":

```
git.x86_64                       1.8.3.1-23.el7_8                         @updates
```

"git --version"

```
git version 2.8.0
```

Gitlab web intefrace -> Admin area -> Overview -> Gitaly Servers

```
git version 2.29.0
```

"whereis git":

```
git: /usr/bin/git /usr/local/git /usr/local/git/bin/git /usr/share/man/man1/git.1.gz /usr/src/git-2.8.0/git.c /usr/src/git-2.8.0/git.rc /usr/src/git-2.8.0/git.spec /usr/src/git-2.8.0/git.o /usr/src/git-2.8.0/git
```

Thank you

EDIT:

```
su git
which git 
   => /usr/local/git/bin/git 
/usr/local/git/bin/git --version 
   => git version 2.8.0
```

gitlab.yml:

```
git: /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git --version 
   => git version 2.29.0
```

So I can `yum remove git` and `rm -rf /usr/local/git/` because gitlab use `/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git`?

Comment: Try `su git` to login as the _git_ user then run `which git` as the git user. See also [the git installation documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/installation.html#git). It may be changed in your `gitlab.yml` configuration file.

Comment: @sytech I have edited my answer thanks to your suggestions. Can you take a look at it please?